# node inspector installation error

Tags: javascript, node.js

While installing node inspector I am getting this error -

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "node-inspector"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! v8-debug@0.7.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the v8-debug@0.7.7 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fal
lback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the v8-debug package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs v8-debug
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls v8-debug
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you try before installing this : node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Comment: yes its giving node-pre-gyp command not found